# Spring Rest service @RequestBody nested json parsing failed

Tags: json, jackson, spring-rest

- Spring 4.3.2
- Jackson 2.7.0

I have created microservice using spring rest. I have a requirement that the RequestBody should have a nested json.

**RequestWrapper.java:**

```
public class RequestWrapper implements Serializable{ 
private String id;
private String message; // json in string format
/**
getter & setter
**/
}
```

The message attribute is dynamic, for instance, for one request it may have json of "Person" object, fo another request it may have different object.

Everything worked well when I had the nested json as string and later converted to actual object
Ex:

```
{
"id":"sample",
"message":"{\"age\":\"12\"}"
}
```

**Controller Sample:**

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class RequestController{
@RequestMapping(value = "/request.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*/*", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseWrapper handleRequest(@RequestBody RequestWrapper requestWrapper,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person person= mapper.readValue(requestWrapper.getMessage(), Person.class);
    }
}
```

Junit test case were also successfully executed with this approach.

Now I have modified the **RequestWrapper.java**, to have the type of message attribute as **Object** instead of **String**

```
public class RequestWrapper<Object extends Serializable> implements Serializable{
private String id;
    private Object message; // Changed to Object
    /**
    getter & setter
    **/
    }
```

Changed the **Controller class** as below

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class CipherController{
@RequestMapping(value = "/request.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*/*", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseWrapper handleRequest(@RequestBody RequestWrapper requestWrapper,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person person= (Person)requestWrapper.getMessage();
}
}
```

the new json format now looks like below:

Ex:

```
{
"id":"sample",
"message":{"age":"12"}
}
```

When I execute the Junit test case, I get below exception

```
WARNING: Failed to read HTTP message: 

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.io.Serializable, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3e58d65e; line: 1, column: 115] (through reference chain: com.common.model.RequestWrapper["message"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.io.Serializable, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
```

Jackson dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

I assume that Jackson parser could not identify to which object instance the nested json(message) should be mapped to, but I do not know how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is giving you the issue and even telling you the exact location.

> **line: 1, column: 115**] (through reference chain:
>   com.common.model.RequestWrapper["message"]);
>
> Can not construct
>   instance of java.io.Serializable, problem: **abstract types either need
>   to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be
>   instantiated with additional type information**

It makes no sense to have your domain object extend Serializable.

Also beyond that you changed method field type to Object and set a child field of "age" which does not exist as a String field in Object.class.  There is no way for this to be mapped, and Nothing about than JSON is legal for that domain object, and the domain object it self is not legal.